# Why does Xcode say the following expression is not assignable?

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
 self.messageView.frame.size.height = self.messageView.frame.size.height + notesHeight;
```

notesHeight is a CGFloat.

Comment: self.messageView.frame.size.height may be read only?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are able to assign the frame, but not the fields of frame

```
CGRect temp = self.messageView.frame;
temp.size.height = temp.size.height + notesHeight;
self.messageView.frame = temp;
```

Comment: Note: A frame doesn't have properties, it has fields.

Answer (score 10):

Dot syntax is just syntax sugar.

In this case, this code:

```
self.messageView.frame.size.height = 0;
```

Dropping the dot syntax, which causes confusion in some cases about exactly what's happening, it looks like this:

```
[[self messageView] frame].size.height = 0;
```

In C terms, that's like this:

```
ViewGetFrame(GetMessageView(self)).size.height = 0;
```

You can't set a field of a function result structure this way. (And even if you could, it wouldn't affect the original but only a copy.)

Note that Apple *does* handle some other things that don't seem like they should work based on these rules automatically (though they didn't when dot syntax was first introduced).

Assuming `foo` is a NSInteger property, for instance:

```
self.foo++;
```

The Wikipedia article on Value has a section on assignment that might clarify the strut problem:

- [Value (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)), Assignment: l-values and r-values

I'm not aware of any place where Apple defines things that work anyway…

Comment: This is the better answer.  Great explanation.

Comment: Unfortunately, Apple's muddied this a bit in recent years. Thanks for drawing my attention back here. :)